# Does changing page state affect static rendering in Gatsby.js?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

Does updating state on a page component do anything to make Gatsby render that page dynamically, or does it remain statically rendered?

For context, I want to use `useReducer` in a page component to handle audio, but I don’t want to hurt the SEO by triggering client-side only rendering.

Comment: Any examples of your code would highly be appreciated.

Comment: @filipvkovic There really isn't a need for a code sample for this. The case is explained sufficiently for an objective answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your page will still be built as a static HTML file that works well with SEO. When the page is requested, React will hydrate the existing HTML (the DOM) and take over from there. When you then make a change to state, for example using a reducer hook, and render new markup, React will update the DOM for the user viewing the page. Your static HTML file on the server will remain as it was when you ran `gatsby build`.

In this sense, Gatsby generates a statically rendered website that has the full dynamic capabilities of React on the client side.